# Flask sqlalchemy and mysql error when creating database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get my flask application to work with a mysql database instead of sqlite and got the following error when trying to create database with db.create_all()

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

If it helps, I'm trying to use a remote mysql server and I'm running Ubuntu Linux on my programming computer.
I already did `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` and it looks like that is installed.

My config class has `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://username:password@server/db'` in it with the correct information inserted

Answer (score 0):

Your URI looks correct. There's a few things you can try.

Since you are using Flask, you can try using flask-mysqldb.

If you want to use ORM then try flask-sqlalchemy.

You could also instead just try making a virtual environment to install modules in. Localizing modules for apps helps since there are no conflicts between the app's modules and your system's (Ubuntu) modules.